# Sorting a listing based on 2 things: 'DATE' and 'STATUS'

Tags: mysql

I have a database table from which I am fetching some values to list them on website. I need to sort that listing based on DATE so that the recent items comes up and specially those whose STATUS is "In Process".

Is this possible in MySQL?

Comment: Of course possible. `.... WHERE `status`="In Process" ORDER BY your_date_field DESC.`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure 100% what you're trying to do here but, here are two quick examples:

1. Sort by date then by status

> SELECT *
>   FROM SomeTable
>   ORDER BY Date DESC, Status

2. Get results where status is "In Process" and then sort by Date

> SELECT * 
>   FROM SomeTable
>   WHERE Status = 'In Process'
>   ORDER BY Date

Comment: Thanks. I sorted it out myself. I was trying to orderby listing through 'Date' and 'Status' but wanted those entries at top which are latest in terms of date but also have status 'In Progress'. Orderby in case of Status was not working fine because I wanted particular value of status to be checked and promoted upwards.